# Update to Exclusive lock conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, locking

SQL Server 2008R2 - ReadCommitted Isolation Level

I am trying to work out exactly when SQL server will convert an update lock to an Exclusive lock. For example I have the table dbo.TableA. dbo.TableA has two Columns PKCol1 and NCCol2. PKCol1 is a clustered index and NCCol2 has a Non-clustered index on it. If I were to execute

```
BEGIN TRAN  

DELETE
FROM dbo.TableA 
WHERE NCCol2 = 1

COMMIT TRANSACTION
```

And the optimiser chose to scan NCCol2 to find all candidate records, would the non-clustered index operator scan all records in the index. Adding an update lock to each candidate record until it had scanned the entire index, before the clustered index delete operator then converted those locks to exclusive locks and deleted.

Or would the non-clustered index operator scan each record in turn adding update locks to candidate records, evaluate if the row was a match and if it was convert the update lock to a exclusive lock.

Basically which operator converts the update lock to an exclusive lock, the non-clustered index scan once the scan has identified that the record is a match or clustered index delete once candidate rows have been identified and passed to it?

Books online tells me

Update (U)

Used on resources that can be updated. Prevents a common form of deadlock that occurs when multiple sessions are reading, locking, and potentially updating resources later

and

Exclusive (X)

Used for data-modification operations, such as INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE. Ensures that multiple updates cannot be made to the same resource at the same time.

**Additional Information 1**

I was actually investigating a deadlock which occurred on the non-unique non-clustered INT Index2 below after the optimiser chose the following plan

[image: Non-Clustered Index Scan]
The deadlock translated as

1. Victim took an update lock on dbo.Table1 Index2 row1
2. Owner took an eXclusive lock on dbo.Table1 Index2 row2
3. Victim waited for an update lock on dbo.Table1 Index2 row2
4. Owner waited for an update lock on dbo.Table1 Index2 row1

It was my understanding that each operator in an execution plan was executed in its entirety in order from right to left top to bottom. But also my understanding that an update lock was only converted to an exclusive lock during an UPDATE/INSERT or DELETE i.e. the clustered index delete operator. Because of this I was unsure why the owner in step 2 had an exclusive lock on Index2 row2, which would suggest that it was at the clustered index delete step, but was still waiting for an update lock which would then suggest that it was also the non-clustered index scan step. How could it be at both steps at the same time?

However if you think that both update and exclusive locks are taken during the index scan then this deadlock would make more sense.

After a recompile the optimiser chose to seek on the clustered index with no problems

[image: Clustered Index Delete]
@Bogdan Sahlean & @brian - many thanks for your help and advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context:

-The target table of DELETE statement has a UNIQUE clustered index (PK) and a non-clustered index.

-Clustered index's key is `IDA`.

-Non-clustered index's key is `NCCol2`.

-`TableA` content:

```
-- Clustered index (C index)
NCCol2 IDA lockhash (these values are the "identifier" of locks)
------ --- --------------
1      11  (29cf3326f583)
2      22  (31178495a25a)

-- Non-Clustered index (NC index)
NCCol2 lockhash
------ --------------
1      (8194443284a0)
2      (61a06abd401c)
```

In this context:

1. SQL Server will choose an `Index Seek` (on non-clustered index with `NCCol2` key) to find the records and a [Clustered Index Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187951(v=sql.105).aspx) operator to delete the records:
   [image]
2. `Index Seek` (on `NCCol2`) operator finds the records using this predicate (`NNCol2=1`),
3. For every record from non-clustered index an `U` lock is taken (see lockhash `(8194443284a0)`) and another `U` lock is taken on corresponding record from clustered index (PK; see lockhash `(29cf3326f583)`),
4. Then the previous `U` lock on clustered index record (lockhash `(29cf3326f583)`) is converted to `X` lock and the `U` lock on non-clustered index records (lockhash `(8194443284a0)`) is converted, also, to `X` lock.
5. The records from both indexes are deleted (in my opinion this is the moment for deleting these records) and the previous `X` locks are released.
6. Find another row using the non-clustered index > go to step #2.

You could intercept these events (`Lock:Aquired` and `Lock:Released`) using SQL Profiler (or server traces, extended events):
[image]

**TLTR:** Index Seek (find a record) > U lock on NC index record > U lock on C index record >  U -> X for C index record > U -> X for NC index record > delete records > repeat (find another row).

**Edit 1:**
That `Scan` could have many reasons:

1) Some [implicit conversions](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/implicit-conversions-that-cause-index-scans/) (as brian pointed out) generated by type precedence (`1` will be a `TINYINT` if database is configured for `Simple Parametrization` or `1` will have the same type as column's type if database is configured for  `Force Parametrization`).

2) Index could be disabled.

3) It's a filtered index ([link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174393.aspx)) or is an index defined on a computed column and the settings ([link: SET Option Requirements](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189292.aspx)) are inappropriate.

4) It's a filtered index and that database has `Parametrization Forced` setting activated.

5) [Low probability] It's a small table and (for some reason) SQL Server choose an `Scan` instead of `Seek`.

Comment: +1 for the internals @Bogdan. This will hold true as long as NCCol2 is the same type as the equality value it's being compared against. For example, if NCCol2 is varchar(25) and the equality value is int, it will be an nc scan as data type precedence requires that the varchar side gets an implicit conversion to int before comparison. If you haven't taken this into account, you obviously work with much smarter developers than I do.

Comment: @brian: Thanks. I agree, but adding information regarding implicit/explicit conversions to my answer wasn't my intention. Jonathan Kehayias have a very good blog post on this subject: [link](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/jonathan/implicit-conversions-that-cause-index-scans/).

Comment: +1 again. Agreed but the OP jumps straight into the optimizer choosing scan. This leads me to wonder if there isn't a data type mismatch in the issue that he/she is trying to understand. Either that or NCCol2 = 1 has a very low selectivity and a scan is cheaper than a seek.  Don't get me wrong, you couldn't have done a better job of explaining the lock escalation.